# Which data types should I use?

Tags: mysql

I am unsure of which data types to use for the following attributes:

- A phone number (which is made up of 10 numbers)
- A client name
- A numeric product ID that acts as a Primary Key
- The location/state of the client (which only has 1 out of 8 possible values)

Im not sure of whether to use CHAR or VARCHAR for some of these, or if there is another type I should use.

Comment: Please refer this link [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. phone number -> decimal(10, 0)
2. name -> varchar(length)
3. productId -> integer unsigned (you can use autoincrement)
4. location -> enum('possible value 1', 'possible value 2', ...)

Answer (score 2):

1. INTEGER (Always used for numeric numbers)
   (If you are allowing "+" & etc. use VARCHAR)
2. CHAR   (for characters)
3. INTEGER (as mentioned above)
4. VARCHAR (It accepts both the character and the number)

> Note: You should use "varchar" for all you needs.

Comment: This is wrong. CHAR doesn’t mean it wouldn’t accept numbers. Phone numbers shouldn’t be treated as integers/numbers. They’re strings. Integer can’t even handle 10 numbers if the first is anything else than 1 or 2.

Comment: read it twice, Sir! "You can use "varchar" for all you needs."

Comment: Doesn’t make it any more correct. And “can” doesn’t mean they should.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the difference between Char, Varchar will help you out.

- Char is fixed length.
- Varchar is variable-length. 
  So in case, you have some fixed length variables like Gender, you can go with char, If you have some variable length variable like Name in your case, you can go with Varchar.